# Does anyone have any walking patterns for a Biped Scout? (LYNXmotion)

Tags: walk

I recently got a LYNX Biped Scout and found that it is really hard to actually come up with a working "Gait" or walking pattern.

Making a servo move is easy, that's not the problem, I previously built a robotic arm from scratch (I have pictures if anyone is interested) and that one can be controlled via Arduino and a few potentiometers as it only has 4 degrees of freedom so it's not too hard to keep track of the different limbs.

However the Scout is a different beast entirely. It's a purpose built kit with 12 servos and to control them I'm using the LYNX SSC-32 Sequencer which is distributed freely on their website. The only problem is that making them all move in sequence to produce a convincing walking motion is actually really hard.

Has anyone got any patterns for this robot they would be happy to share?

Comment: I think this question should be edited a bit, because in its current form it's offtopic -- it's not really seeking an answer.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Nik-Nak, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it is a good idea to include details of what what you would like to achieve, what you have tried, what you expected to see & what you actually saw. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works & edit your question according to [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I recently acquired a scout like you and am facing a similar problem.
I don't know of any areas with gaits predefined, so you'll have to experiment.
For short term you could hard-code a walking gait into a micro-controller.
For long term you will need to program a micro-controller with inverse kinematics
and possibly Zero Moment Point (or you could hard-code balance) and then feed that data for foot positions.

Hope this helps :)